# Insert on conflict with query parameters

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

How could i use psycopg2 query parameters with on conflict? 
for example, i have this data:

```
#This is the data for the insert query
q_values = {'customer_app_id': '35', 'email': 'my@email.com', 'access_counter': 1, 'company_name': 'twitter', 'status': 'start'}

#This is the data for the on conflict query part
conflict_values = {'access_counter': +1, 'status': 'check', 'status_info': 'already exist'}
```

This is the query:

```
insert into access (customer_app_id,email,access_counter,company_name,status) 
values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT (customer_app_id,email)  DO UPDATE SET 
%s,%s,%s RETURNING *
```

Then i run this line:

```
q_values = q_values.update(conflict_values)
cursor.execute(query, q_values)
```

First, how at all to run on conflict with query parameters ?

Second, the update i am doing with the dict is not good since if it will be duplicate keys it will merge them, and then number of parameters wont be equal to number of values.

- and access_counter +1 - on conflict i'm trying to increase the access _counter by 1

please can you help ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To run on conflict with query parameter:
The %s has to be replaced by %(key value that you want to access)s. This has to be done since you are using a dictionary. So in this case the query would look as follows-

**insert into access (customer_app_id,email,access_counter,company_name,status) 
values (%(customer_app_id)s,%(email)s,%(access_counter)s,%(company_name)s,%(status)s) ON CONFLICT**

To update the access counter:
A separate dictionary need not be used. Rather **ON CONFLICT** you can directly make changes in the database. So in this case the final query would look as follows-

**insert into access (customer_app_id,email,access_counter,company_name,status) 
values (%(customer_app_id)s,%(email)s,%(access_counter)s,%(company_name)s,%(status)s) ON CONFLICT (customer_app_id,email) DO UPDATE SET access_counter = access.access_counter + 1**

In case you want to update one of your column values to a new value sent in the **INSERT** query then you will have to use EXCLUDED keyword.

**Example(this example is not related to the question)**:

**INSERT INTO user_details (user_id, username,email,last_login)
                            VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s)
                            ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO UPDATE
                            SET  last_login = EXCLUDED.last_login**

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing a dictionary of values (instead of a list or a tuple), I think you need to use `%(name)s` placeholders, not `%s`.

This means you can give the placeholders alternative names, so they don't conflict in the `q_values` dictionary.

See the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters) for details.